# Extending a tidy tibble to its original form

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a tidy tibble.

```
Tibble <- data.frame(Doc_ID = c(1, 9, 9, 67),
                     Compartment = c("Car", "Truck", "Bus", "Plane"),
                     Count = c(3, 2, 1, 5))
```

I need to extend it back to its original form.

```
Result <- data.frame(Doc_ID = c(1,1,1,9,9,9,67,67,67,67,67), 
                     Compartment = c("Car","Car","Car","Truck","Truck","Bus",
                                     "Plane","Plane","Plane","Plane","Plane"))
```

Does the `tidy()` function have an opposite function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `uncount` from `tidyr` to expand the data to long format by specifying the `weights` as 'Count'

```
library(tidyr)
uncount(Tibble, Count)
```